# Undo changes on remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to undo all changes on **remote** repository so that it represents the state as it was **after** commit id `bd5bf14`, how can I achieve this?

This is my current graph:

```
* 299b710 (HEAD -> master, origin-prod/master) Separation of objects 
* 2c3a084  bifurcation
*   bd5bf14 Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.********
|\
| * 63b5065 changed downtime 
| * dba5e46 added module
| * 9f52520 added module for Infra
| * 287e409 added module for Infra
| * 7e38cdf added module for Infra
* | be1dd06 Separation of objects
|/
* 934feb2 downtime added.
*   f41b8a6 Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.*********
|\
| * dc09c13 Update environment
* | 12ca95d Several changes.
|/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go back to `bd5bf14` on the remote only, you can force-push like this:

```
git push -f origin-prod bd5bf14:master
```

If you want to go back locally and on the remote, you can hard-reset to the desired state and then force-push:

```
git reset --hard bd5bf14
git push -f origin-prod master
```

Be aware that this removes the commits from the remote branch and might have an impact on other developers. A safe way to undo the changes is to revert them which generates a commit without rewriting history:

```
git revert --no-commit bd5bf14..HEAD
git commit
git push origin-prod master
```